# Failing to untar

Tags: ubuntu, tar, split, hashsum, large-files

I am dealing with transferring large files from one machine to another (600GB+) and I'm tarring them up using

```
tar -cpvzf file.tar.gz -C PATH_TO_DIR DIR
```

Once finished with the tarring process, the following is done:

```
split -d -b 2G file.tar.gz file_part_
```

This creates a bunch of file_part_00, file_part_01, ... until the whole file is split into 2GB chunks. Before transferring the file, I loop through each part in the directory the tar was split and collect their md5 hashes using an equivalent to:

```
md5sum PART_NAME >> list_md5.start
```

Once each part has been hashed, I do the following:

```
sort -u list_md5.start
```

(This sorts them and remove duplicates, just to be safe ya know)

The parts are then transferred one by one in the order they're in the list_md5.start. Once they arrive on the other computer, their md5 hash is collected using the same method but in a different list let's call it list_md5_2.start. After the transfer, before putting the parts back together, I run the following:

```
diff list_md5.start list_md5_2.start
```

If no difference is found, I continue to the next part. Otherwise, I give up and delete all the parts. When it comes to putting them back together I do the following:

```
cat file_part_* > file.tar.gz.incomplete
```

(The incomplete is there because I have a watchdog waiting to untar any .tar.gz it comes across).
Once the cat is done, the file is renamed using:

```
mv file.tar.gz.incomplete file.tar.gz
```

At this point, the watchdog detects it and untars it using:

```
tar -C DEST -xzf file.tar.gz --totals --unlink-first --recursive-unlink
```

At this point, I get an error I can't debug:

```
Tar Failed 2
gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
 /PATH/TO/DEST
```

After untarring, the tar is removed regardless if it failed or not (No point in keeping large files that failed to untar).

It is worth noting that sometimes the md5sum don't match up which also results in stopping the process (this is checked before the `cat` assembling step).

I have tried ensuring the names were not invalid. I've tried changing the part size to smaller sizes. I've tried manually going through the process and still either got an issue with a mismatch in md5sum or the EOF error.

This is all done on Ubuntu machines which have both been updated (No update pending).

Does anyone have an idea as to how to solve this issue?

Comment: *It is worth noting that sometimes the md5sum don't match up.* At this point you can start over.

Comment: Sorry, missed that. Will edit that in. Thank you!

Comment: The environment does not allow using sftp/scp. We go through a diode. They're split up because of intermediary storage restrictions.

Comment: Thank you for explaining why you split the file and not transfer it via sftp.

Comment: Have you considered calculating the master hash of `file.tar.gz` before the split, and comparing to the hash of `file.tar.gz.incomplete` before doing the rename?

Comment: I have not. But what would be the solution to when they don't match? Should I re-attempt to cat the parts together?

Comment: Is the output of `uname -ip` the same on both systems?

Comment: Yes, it is the same on both systems.

Comment: Make sure that your first `tar -cpvzf ...` is running without any errors, that the return code (`echo $?`) is 0 and that the disk space is sufficient.

Comment: You seem to be missing the `-f` option for that extraction at the end.

Comment: The compression is running without error. In addition, the missing `-f` would not be an issue. I can't confirm if it's a typo right now, but I can confirm that the command is correct in terms of extracting a source file. I haven't gotten any errors related to the file not existing and the same command works for other smaller tars. The important options that deal with how the file is extracted are present.

Comment: I've updated the question to correct the missing `-f` typo.

Comment: Is the split generating more than 100 files?  Is it possible the `cat file_part_*` is getting them in a different order?  This can happen if this is (a) *BSD (i.e., not "GNU" split), or (b) less likely, a very old "coreutils" even if you are using Linux.

Comment: It is splitting more than 100 files. I was thinking that might be the case as well but I'm not sure if there's a way to test if that's the issue to be honest. But I have updated the system recently so I don't think it has to do with outdated tools.

Comment: The issue seems related to storage space. I posted an answer to the question with my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved by adding additional storage space. To be specific, I added a 2TB hdd which is used to hold the tar while it's split on it. Originally, the whole process was done on a 6TB hdd with other large files on it giving us at most 3TB storage space to work with. The issue was noticed when we had something large downloading in the background which took up most of the space reproducing the broken tar issue from the question.

This solution is probably not the most elegant solution, but removing the original file after being tarred would involve significant overhead which would have taken more time than simply adding additional storage space.

In case someone stumbles upon this question, and is going to go through the same route as me, here's the steps I followed to add the new hdd:
https://askubuntu.com/a/125277/

I would like to point out someone did suggest checking if the storage space is sufficient and I would like to give them credit. Here's suggestion:

> Make sure that your first tar -cpvzf ... is running without any errors, that the return code (echo $?) is 0 and that the disk space is sufficient. 
>   – [Cyrus](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/74329/cyrus) Aug 16 at 19:37

However, this suggestion was incomplete as at the time, there was enough storage space for tarring so it never returned any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Rsync is a free software utility for Unix- and Linux-like systems that copies files and directories from one host to another.

Use rsync to transfer file from one system to other.
You can use screen and the start rsync then deattach screen

Rsync is considered to be a lightweight application because file transfers are incremental -- after the initial full transfer, only bits in files that have been changed are transferred. Rsynch is often used to provide offsite backups by syncing data to a remote machine outside a firewall. It is also used for mirroring Web sites.

Comment: Although all of this is _true_ it does not in any way address the issue with the seemingly corrupt `tar` archive in the question. Also note that the user mentions that `scp` and `sftp` can't be used (in comments), which likely means that the SSH transport (which `rsync` uses) probably can't be used at all.